# Visualizing cpt.mean plot so that the dates appear on the x axis

Tags: r, plot, time-series

Can't figure out how to visualize a cpt.mean plot so that it displays the appropriate 'Night' on the x axis. I'm just getting the row number which isn't very intuitive.

My data is set up like this:

```
Rows: 132
Columns: 6
$ Night         <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, ~
$ Site_AN       <chr> "DI_231", "DI_231", "DI_231", "DI_231", "DI_231", "DI_231"~
$ vocalisations <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ~
$ NDSI.default  <dbl> -0.225862044, -0.360887801, 0.024681598, -0.126896366, -0.093891761, ~
```

Then I run this code for cpt.mean

```
x -> cpt.mean(df$vocalisations, method="AMOC")
```

Then plot it:

```
plot(x)
```

It comes up with the y axis as the mean vocalisations and the x axis as 'Time'. However instead of 'Night' like I want it to be, it is just the file number.

Is there anyway to remedy this? I imagine I have to set up my data in some way (perhaps as a time series) but each attempt at that has proven unsuccessful.

EDIT. I should also note that the frequency of 'Night' isnt uniform. Sometimes there are 6 samples taken in one night and sometimes there are 5 samples taken in one night